# Why is this Pandas set_table_styles directive not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, html-table, styles

Pandas set_table_styles() seems not to work. Following the [example in the user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html).

```
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

styles = {
'B': [ dict( selector='',   props=[('color', 'green')] )],
'C': [ dict( selector='td', props=[('color', 'red')]   )],
}

html = ( 
df.loc[:3].style
            .set_table_styles( styles )
            .set_caption( "this isn't bloody working" )
)

html
```

This is supposed to produce a table with green font in column A and red font in column B. It gives me a table with regular formatting, implying an error in the style directive.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So this gives me green in column `B` and red in column `C` since those are the keys in the `styles` dict. but otherwise is working on my end. How are you using this code? Is this `Jupyter`?

Comment: Yes. It seems the problem is that I am using v1.1.5 and .set_table_styles was introduced with 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that I am using v1.1.5 of Pandas and the .set_table_styles styler method was introduced with 1.2.